# What is the Clear Purpose of SparseBooleanArray?? [ I referred official android site for this ]

Tags: java, android

I referred the android doc site for "SparseBooleanArray" class but still not getting idea of that class about what is the purpose of that class?? For what purpose we need to use that class??

Here is the Doc Link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From what I get from the documentation it is for mapping Integer values to booleans.

That is, if you want to map, if for a certain userID a widget should be shown and some userIDs have already been deleted, you would have gaps in your mapping.

Meaning, with a normal array, you would create an array of size=maxID and add a boolean value to element at index=userID. Then when iterating over the array, you would have to iterate over maxID elements in the worst case and have to check for `null` if there is no boolean for that index (eg. the ID does not exist). That  is really inefficient.

When using a hashmap to do that you could map the ID to the boolean, but with the added overhead of generating the hashvalue for the key (that is why it is called **hash**map), which would ultimately hurt performance firstly in CPU cycles as well as RAM usage.

So that SparseBooleanArray seems like a good middleway of dealing with such a situation.

**NOTE:** Even though my example is really contrieved, I hope it illustrates the situation.

Comment: Most of the performance optimizations come from not having to autobox the primitives into objects - less objects created, less GC.

Comment: thank you all for your wonder full comments. everyone deserves the +. And i did. You all gave me couple of new concepts which i was not aware. :) . thank you again.

Answer (score 6):

Like the javadoc says, `SparseBooleanArrays map integers to booleans` which basically means that it's like a map with Integer as a key and a boolean as value (Map).

However it's more efficient to use in this particular case `It is intended to be more efficient than using a HashMap to map Integers to Booleans`

Hope this clears out any issues you had with the description.

Comment: thanks a lot. Can you please tell me by default what value it will take for boolean? true or false??

Comment: @RipalTamboli `get(key)` returns `false` if not found but there's also `get(key, valueIfKeyNotFound)` to supply your own default.

Answer (score 4):

I found a very specific and wonderful use for the sparse boolean array.

You can put a true or false value to be associated with a position in a list.

For example: List item #7 was clicked, so putting 7 as the key and true as the value.

Comment: it would also be nice to add an example (code application) as well

Comment: I would but that takes time and I don't have a lot of it these days unfortunately. People don't seem to value code examples. I put them up, I get no replies or votes up or down. Then look at the 2 relies ahead of mine with up-votes, they have no code. I am learning from what I see and taking the time to write code examples doesn't seem to be what people really want. Thanks for your reply though!

Answer (score 0):

There can be three ways to store resource id's

1 **Array**

Boolean array containing id's as indexes.If we have used that id set it to true else false

Though all the operations are fast but this implementation **will require huge amount of space**.So it can't be used

**High Space Complexity**

2 **HashMap**

**Key-ID**

**Value-Boolean True/False**

Using this we need to process each id using the hashing function which will consume memory.Also there may be some **empty locations** where no id will be stored and we also need to deal with crashes.So due to **usage complexity** and medium space complexity, it is not used.

**Medium Space Complexity**

3 **SparseBooleanArray**

It is **middle way**.It uses **mapping** and **Array Implementation**

**Key - ID**

**Value - Boolean True/False**

It is an ArrayList which stores id's in an increasing order.So minimum space is used as it only contains id's which are being used.For searching an id binary search is used.
Though Binary Search O(logn) is slower than hashing O(1) or Array O(1),i.e. **all the operations Insertion, Deletion, Searching will take more time** but there is least memory wastage.So to save memory we prefer SparseBoolean Array

**Least Space Complexity**