# How to remove selected TextViews from my ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to implement removing chosen `TextViews` from my `ListView`.

The one way to do this according to android dev reference is by using `SparseBooleanArray`. The problem is, I don't understand the logic behing this array and every time I call the `getCheckedItemPositions()`, method returns the **empty** array.

**Here is the sample of my code:**

```
List<Record> records = new RecordDAO(this).findAll(); //gets all records saved in ListView from database 
SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions = recordListView.getCheckedItemPositions();

for(int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++){
   if(checkedPositions.valueAt(i)){
        System.out.println("chosen at pos: " + i);
   }
}
```

**I choose the last 2 TextViews press button**

[image]

**and the output is:**

```
I/System.out: chosen at pos: 0
I/System.out: chosen at pos: 1
```

- How do I properly solve my problem?
- Can anyone explain me how does
  the SparseBooleanArray working?

Comment: refer to (this)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822708/what-is-the-clear-purpose-of-sparsebooleanarray-i-referred-official-android] link I found it helpful.

Comment: May be useful -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558591/remove-listview-items-in-android

Comment: first link was helpful after I actually solved the problem.